# JAVAFX: Changing Stage window color with JFOENIX

Tags: javafx

I've been using [JFOENIX](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix) library to make a material design desktop application, and From the JFOENIX demo, I've seen that the stage window is change to something like the below image:

[image]

I wanted to do the same, but I found nothing topic about it. Anyone here is using JFOENIX and achieve the same as I want? How to do it?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [this demo](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/demos/MainDemo.java). You can create a JFoenix decorator with the following code:

```
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXDecorator;

Parent root = something; // your root container

JFXDecorator decorator = new JFXDecorator(stage, root);
decorator.setCustomMaximize(true);
Scene scene = new Scene(decorator, 500, 500);
```

This will result in a black decorator. After looking at [this css file](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/blob/master/demo/src/main/resources/css/jfoenix-main-demo.css) I thought you could change the color with the following css code:

```
.jfx-decorator {
    -fx-decorator-color: blue;
}

.jfx-decorator .jfx-decorator-buttons-container {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-decorator-color;
}

.jfx-decorator .resize-border {
    -fx-border-color: -fx-decorator-color;
    -fx-border-width: 0 4 4 4;
}
```

Unfortunately, the decorator was still black. I couldn't find any additional documentation so I really can't say how you can change the decorator color. I hope I could help.

Comment: your answer helped me change the color. Have you added String uri = getClass().getResource(CSS_FILE_NAME).toExternalForm();
        scene.getStylesheets().add(uri) ?

Comment: I probably added the css file in the wrong place. Anyway, it's good to know that the css is working, after all.

Answer (score 3):

I can't find any direct method to change jfx-decorator color directly, so I used the following code and that works for me!

Inside your java code,

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXML_FILE"));
/*...*/
JFXDecorator decorator = new JFXDecorator(stage , root);
decorator.setCustomMaximize(true);                  
String uri = getClass().getResource("CSS_PATH").toExternalForm();
Scene scene = new Scene(decorator);
scene.getStylesheets().add(uri) ;
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
```

Inside the css file,

```
.jfx-decorator {
    -fx-decorator-color: #272727;
}

.jfx-decorator .jfx-decorator-buttons-container {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-decorator-color;

}

.jfx-decorator .resize-border {
    -fx-border-color: -fx-decorator-color;
    -fx-border-width: 0 2 2 2;
}
```